# Working with remove clicked element and scoping in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="BlogData" >
    <form ng-submit="removeTodo()">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="blog in bloges">
      {{blog.name}}
      <p>{{blog.mobile}}</p>
       <p>{{blog.description}}</p> 
       <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="remove">
       <p></p>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </form>

    <form ng-submit="addTodo()">
      <label>Name:</label><input type="text" ng-model="todoName"  size="30"
             placeholder="add your name">
      <label>Mobile:</label><input type="number" ng-model="todoMobile"  size="30"
             placeholder="add your mobile">
      <label>Description:</label><input type="text" ng-model="todoDesc"  size="30"
             placeholder="add some description">
      <hr>
      <h1>Hello {{todoName }}!</h1>  
      <h1>Your mobile is {{todoMobile}}!</h1>
      <h1>About my Details :-  {{todoDesc}}!</h1>
      <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="add">
    </form>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function BlogData($scope) {
  $scope.bloges = [
    {"name": "Nexus S",
     "mobile": "858485454",
     "description": "The nest to seehow it works"},
    {"name": "Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi",
     "mobile": "8584453454",
     "description": "The nest to ytrb  dsfhgs gvd m seehow it works"},
    {"name": "MOTOROLA XOOM™",
     "mobile": "443485454",
     "description": "The nest bla bla  vd fg hvto seehow it works"}
  ];

  $scope.addTodo = function() {
    $scope.bloges.push({name:$scope.todoName, mobile:$scope.todoMobile, description:$scope.todoDesc, done:false});
    $scope.todoName = '';
    $scope.todoMobile = '';
    $scope.todoDesc = '';
  };

  $scope.removeTodo = function() {
    $scope.bloges.pop({name:$scope.todoName, mobile:$scope.todoMobile, description:$scope.todoDesc, done:false});
    $scope.todoName = '';
    $scope.todoMobile = '';
    $scope.todoDesc = '';
  };

}

var blogApp = angular.module('blogApp',[]);
blogApp.controller('BlogData', BlogData);
```

I am facing problem while deleting the element. When I am clicking a remove its removing the last element. I tried splice as well but not able to reach success.

Here is a <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/554/)</kbd>

***Some concern related Angular implementations :-***

1. We need to use form action `ng-submit="addTodo()"` or we need to use `<button ng-click="addTodo(">` please differentiate.
2. Can anyone define the proper **scoping in angular** with practical manner in full flex web application ?

Please guide me.. Thanks !!

Comment: `That will be best if somebody will create a jsfiddle for that.` . Also will be great if you post Fiddle with this code, please

Comment: @MAxim I was not able to create It.. I will try to check it again.. I wish to thank you for your invaluable support.

Comment: IS this all your code? can copy/paste to Fiddle?

Comment: @Maxim I have created it before .. http://jsfiddle.net/88ZfB/   But I am getting some error. I have loaded Angular as well.. Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try two options `filter` and `splice`

**Filter**

*HTML*

Add `ng-click="theFilter(blog)`

```
<input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="remove"  ng-click="splice(blog, bloges)">
```

- to use [_filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter):

like:

*JS*

```
  $scope.theFilter = function(field) {
   $scope.bloges = _.filter($scope.bloges, function(nodeClient) {
      return !(nodeClient.name == field.name &&
             nodeClient.mobile == field.mobile &&
              nodeClient.description == field.description
             );
     });      
 };
```

See <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/570/)</kbd>

Other way is:

Add `ng-click="splice(blog, bloges)`

**splice**

*HTML*

```
<input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="remove"  ng-click="splice(blog, bloges)">
```

*JS*

```
 $scope.splice = function(field, fields) {     
    fields.splice(fields.indexOf(field), 1);
 };
```

See <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/569/)</kbd>

*as a side note*

How `_filter` works:

filter`_.filter(list, iterator, [context])`
        Alias: **select**
        
        Looks through each value in the **list**, returning an array of all
        the values that pass a truth test (**iterator**). Delegates to the
        native **filter** method, if it exists.

```
var evens = _.filter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], function(num){ return num % 2 == 0; });
=> [2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: +1 for your help..  but I am facing some ReferenceError: _ is not defined while using this code..

Comment: 1 min ill try to fix it in FIddle

Comment: @Neeraj You can use array instead of using json objects that will be better for implementation..

Comment: @MaximShoustin Thank you for your invaluable support !! Answer accepted.. :)

Answer (score 2):

It will remove the last element because of pop. You need to find the index of the element you are looking for and splice it. Using lo-dash for brevity:

```
$scope.removeTodo = function() {
    var index = $scope.bloges.indexOf({name:$scope.todoName, mobile:$scope.todoMobile, description:$scope.todoDesc, done:false}, 0);
    $scope.bloges.splice(index, 1);
    $scope.todoName = '';
    $scope.todoMobile = '';
    $scope.todoDesc = '';
  };
```

Ideally, you'll actually pass the "blog" in from the view so you dont need to make the object representations every time in delete.

```
$scope.removeTodo = function(blog) {
        var index = $scope.bloges.indexOf(blog, 0);
        $scope.bloges.splice(index, 1);
        $scope.todoName = '';
        $scope.todoMobile = '';
        $scope.todoDesc = '';
      };
```

Comment: It comes from underscore/lodash - i just used it for brevity because i didnt want to write out a whole "indexOf" function, which is a common and google-able function to have. I will modify my answer to use it.